# Why applying a const attribute to a pure function cannot reduce elapsed time?

Tags: c, performance, gnu

According to the [GNU document](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html#Common-Function-Attributes):

> `int square (int) __attribute__ ((const))`
> tells GCC that subsequent calls to function square with the same argument value can
> be replaced by the result of the first call regardless of the
> statements in between.

I expect the following code will be slow down when removing `__attribute__((const))` in the function declaration.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

int my_double(int b) __attribute__((const));

//int my_double(int b);


int main(void) {

  long result = 0;

  for (int i = 0; i < INT_MAX/2; i++)
  {
     result += my_double(5);
  }

  printf("%ld\n", result);
}

int my_double(int b) {
  return b*2;
}
```

However, the experiments show that `__attribute__((const))` does not affect timing results significantly. Does anyone know the reason? Thanks.

By the way, I use the following commands to clear any cache that might pollute the timing results of each experiment.

```
  sudo sh -c 'echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches'
  sudo swapoff -a
  sudo swapon -a
```

And use `/usr/bin/time` to time the experiments.

PS. The corresponding assembly is as follows: (I am unfamiliar with assembly)

```
    .file   "attribute-o.c"
    .text
    .section    .rodata
.LC0:
    .string "%ld\n"
    .text
    .globl  main
    .type   main, @function
main:
.LFB0:
    .cfi_startproc
    endbr64
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    subq    $16, %rsp
    movq    $0, -8(%rbp)
    movl    $0, -12(%rbp)
    jmp .L2
.L3:
    movl    $5, %edi
    call    my_double
    cltq
    addq    %rax, -8(%rbp)
    addl    $1, -12(%rbp)
.L2:
    cmpl    $1073741822, -12(%rbp)
    jle .L3
    movq    -8(%rbp), %rax
    movq    %rax, %rsi
    leaq    .LC0(%rip), %rax
    movq    %rax, %rdi
    movl    $0, %eax
    call    printf@PLT
    movl    $0, %eax
    leave
    .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE0:
    .size   main, .-main
    .globl  my_double
    .type   my_double, @function
my_double:
.LFB1:
    .cfi_startproc
    endbr64
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    movl    %edi, -4(%rbp)
    movl    -4(%rbp), %eax
    addl    %eax, %eax
    popq    %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE1:
    .size   my_double, .-my_double
    .ident  "GCC: (Ubuntu 11.2.0-7ubuntu2) 11.2.0"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
    .section    .note.gnu.property,"a"
    .align 8
    .long   1f - 0f
    .long   4f - 1f
    .long   5
0:
    .string "GNU"
1:
    .align 8
    .long   0xc0000002
    .long   3f - 2f
2:
    .long   0x3
3:
    .align 8
4:
```

Comment: did you check the assembly if there is any difference at all?

Comment: No. I check now. Thanks for the reminder.

Comment: The compiler might already know that `my_double(5)` returns 10 and even skip the first call. Maybe you can force the compiler to call the function by moving it into another compilation unit.

Comment: Hint: replace `my_double(5)` (which is pretty pointless anyway) with `my_double(i)` and examine the assembly output of both versions with and without `__attribute__ ((const))`. You'll see the difference.

Comment: @Raildex You are right. The assemblies for both version are identical.

Comment: @Jabberwocky Replacing `my_double(5)` by `my_double(i)` still results in the same assembly.

Comment: Is the `__attribute__`  only needed at prototype? Or might it be needed at the function definition?

Comment: I must admit I never used that attribute. But from the description in the question, how would `my_double(i)` be affected at all? I assume the same arguments need to be identified by the compiler, not during runtime. With argument `i` that would not be possible. And even if it was possible, the argument would never be same.

Comment: Are you compiling with optimization enabled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`__attribute__ ((const))` is about common subexpression elimination *inside the same expression*.

There is no common subexpresson in the expression `my_double(5)`, therefore nothing can be eliminated and the generated code is the same.

If you replace `my_double(5)` with `my_double(5) + my_double(5)`, then there are two common subexpressions. As the compiler does not know what `my_double(5)` does (there may be side effects), `my_double(5)` must be called twice unless the compiler knows that `my_double` has no side effects (because of `__attribute__ ((const))`) and then `my_double(5)` can only be called once and the results can be added.

Check here: https://www.godbolt.org/z/bGnfq9zM5

Comment: I am not the OP but I don't get how "regardless of the statements in between." might match with "subexpressions inside the same expression".

Comment: Thank you! After following your constructive suggestion, the `__attribute__ ((const))` accelerates the run by a factor of 2.32!

Comment: So the example code provided by
https://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/armcc/armcc_chr1359124974244.htm
is extremely misleading although the document is originally designed for ARM compiler.

Comment: @RockyTseng yes, the example is misleading.